# Haskell Tree help

Tags: haskell

Could anyone please help me with my assignment questions? I've done most of it but I'm still stuck on these 3 questions.

Here is the question:

> Consider the following types of *search trees* and *balanced trees*
>
> ```
> data STree = Leaf | Node STree Int STree  
> data Btree = Tip Int | Branch Btree Btree
> ```
>
> whose constructors are subject to the following constraints:
>
> - Values of the form `Node left n right` must have all integers in left being at most `n` and all integers in right being greater than `n`.
> - Values of the form `Branch left right` must have a difference between the numbers of integers in `left` and `right` of at most one.
>
> a) Define a recursive function `stree :: [Int] -> STree` that constructs a search tree from a list of integers.
>
> b) Define a recursive function `btree :: [Int] -> BTree` that constructs a balanced tree from a non-empty list of integers.
>
> c) Using merge, define a recursive function `collapse :: BTree -> [Int]` that collapses a balanced tree to give a sorted list of integers.

Please help me!!!

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Your question has two parts. First, the design of the necessary algorithms with respect to binary tree's. Second, their implementation in Haskell. Clarify how far you have got with the problem, and which step(s) you need help with.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: To "gbacon": In fact, there are 5 questions in this part though, but i've done 2 and stuck on 3 questions above. 

The other 2 questions are: "flatten" and "merge"
{-flatten question-}

flatten             :: Tree -> [Int]
flatten (Leaf n)     = [n]
flatten (Node l n r) = flatten l
                       ++ [n]
                       ++ flatten r

and 
{-merge question-}

merge :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
merge []xs = xs
merge xs[] = xs
merge (x:xs)(y:ys) = if (x<=y) then x:(merge xs(y:ys)) 
   else y:(merge(x:xs)ys)

Answer (score 2):

Don't want to take all the fun, but here is my go at part a.

```
stree :: [Int] -> Stree
stree []     = Leaf
stree (x:xs) = let (left, right) = partition (<= x) xs
               in Stree (stree left) x (stree right)
```

It just takes the components that should be on the left and right and recursively builds the subtrees for each.

Assuming the use of sort is legit, then I'm pretty certain this works for part b.

```
btree :: [Int] -> Btree
btree (x:[]) = Tip x
btree xs     = let len = length xs `div` 2
                   ys = sort xs
               in Branch (btree (take len ys)) (btree (drop len ys))
```

Comment: You can use `partition` instead of the two instances of `filter` in your `stree`: `let (left, right) = partition (<=) xs`.

Comment: Good idea, made the necessary modifications.

Comment: You could also replace take and drop with split.

    (left,right) = splitAt len ys
    in Branch (btree left) (btree right)

Comment: I'm pretty sure from the problem statement that you don't need to sort the balanced tree. At the very least you don't need to do it on every recursive step, since the sublists of `ys` will still be sorted!

Comment: Thanks so much guys, i think i could get some idea for the last question now.

Answer (score 0):

```
stree = foldr insert Leaf
  where insert :: Int -> STree -> STree
        insert i (Node l i' r)  | i <= i'   = Node (insert i l) i' r
                                | otherwise = Node l i' (insert i r)
        insert i (Leaf) = Node Leaf i Leaf
```

This isn't a very efficient solution, nor does it produce a very balanced tree, but it's a good example of how to iteratively build a data structure in Haskell.  Using `foldr` to handle the iteration for us, we insert one element at a time into the tree, passing the new tree into the function that builds the next.  We descend through the tree, until we find a leaf, and replace that `Leaf` with a `Node` to hold the given value.

Answer (score 0):

These are recursive data structures.  Let's start with the Search Tree:

```
data STree = Leaf | Node STree Int STree
```

and all values in the left must be less than the parent, which must be less than all values in the right.  Can you write down the answers for stree [] and stree [x]?  How far can you go?

I'll start:

```
stree [] = Leaf
stree [x] = Node Leaf x Leaf
stree ([x,y]) = if x < y then Node Leaf x (Node Leaf y Leaf) else Node (Node Leaf y Leaf) x Leaf
```

That sort of nested if and node construction is going to get awful pretty fast.  What common sub-expressions can we factor out?

```
singleton x = Node Leaf x Leaf
```

That makes life a little easier:

```
stree [] = Leaf
stree [x] = singleton x
stree ([x,y]) = if x < y then Node Leaf x (singleton y) else Node (singleton y) x Leaf
```

But it doesn't attack the basic problem of the nested if.  One common trick for lists is to take them *one element at a time*.  Can that work for us?

```
addToSTree :: Int -> STree -> STree
addToStree x Leaf = singleton x
addToStree x (Node left n right) | x < n = ...
                                 | otherwise = ...
```

Can you fill in the dots above?  Once you have that, then it'll be time to make a loop over the contents of the list.

BTree can be solved similarly.